# simple search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple search form in rails. In my search view I have two select boxes with fixed values like:

```
SELECT BOX 1          SELECT BOX 2
ALL,                  ALL,
FR,                   FR,
US,                   US,
DE                    DE
```

And I have 2 fields in my DB with `country_from` and `country_to`.

So for making a simple search like from `FR` to `US` I use:

```
@search_result = Load.find(:all, :conditions => "country_from='#{params[:country_from]}' AND country_to='#{params[:country_to]}'" )
```

that is fine, but I need to implement the `ALL` option as well, so when I make a search like from `DE` to `ALL` I get a list with all countries in `country_to`

I image I can do it with ifs...but what would be the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you do:

```
cond = {}
cond[:country_from] = params[:country_from] unless params[:country_from] == "AL"
cond[:country_to] = params[:country_to] unless params[:country_to] == "AL"

@search_result = Load.all(:conditions => cond)
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood it correctly, it would be

```
@search_result = Load.find(:all, :conditions => ["country_from = ? AND country_to IN (?)", params[:country_from], params[:country_to]])
```

Comment: That works in the first case when I have a fixed country from and to value. But when I select ALL it needs to query all from the table. For example from DE to ALL, means query where country_from ='DE'.

Comment: if i understood what you want, this works for you. this search will return, for example, every `Load` with `country_from = DE` and `country_to = [FR, US, DE]`.